# How to get schema(http/https) in jspInit() method?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using jsp file in my application which contains jspInit() method to intialize some resources.
I tried to get the protocol(http/https/ftp) in the init method of jsp file to enable the application url with http/https connection.

## code:

```
<%!public void jspInit() {
       String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
       ServletContext servletContext = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
       //  how to get ServletRequest like servletcontext, So that we can get protocol from servletRequest.

   }
%>
```

I have seen ServletRequest interface has 'getScheme()' method but I dont know how to get the ServletRequest in jspInit().

Could any body tell me how to get the schema in jsp?

Comment: *You can't* get the _request scheme_ in the jspInit method because there is no request from which to get requestUri.

Comment: Thank you @gtosto, May I know is there any to get schema in the jspInit().

Comment: I am sorry, but really there is no way to get request(s) scheme within that method. I tried to write a more esaustive answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*The short answer is:* There is no way to get the uri schema at *initialization time* of a jsp (that is in the jspInit method).

You can not get the schema of a **request** in the jspInit method because there no request. 
The method `ServletRequest.getSchema()` infact extract the scheme part from the url used by a client to issue a request to your jsp page/servlet.
The jspInit method is called by the container when the jsp is initialized, and this happen once time in the servlet lifecycle.
So when the jspInit method is invoked there is no actual request from which get the scheme.

if you need to "enable the application url with http/https connection" the jspInit is not the right place. If for example you are using apache tomcat, 
you could read this tutorial ([configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https](https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/)) or [this ssl-howto](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) on the steps you need to take.

Answer (score 0):

It does not makes sense to access request from jspInit(). Because that gets invoked only during JSP compilation time.

You should be reading the Scheme from the request. Here is the EL for fetching the Scheme from the request in JSP.

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.scheme eq 'https'}">
 //this section will be exectured only if it is Https request.
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ramesh, Yes the implicit objects cannot be accessed by jspInit(). Is this same thing applicable in ServletContextListener also?

Comment: Yes. It applies there too,